# Why would a yocto patch fail under devtool but not during a normal build?

Tags: linux, patch, yocto

I have a set of kernel patches. These all patch nicely and I have a clean Yocto Krogoth build that I use. I recently started looking at using devtool for modifying recipes. It's been handy for the small changes I've made so far. When I try to use it to modify my kernel recipe though the patches all fail. It just says: `can't find file to patch`.

Is the environment and search paths of a devtool environment different to that when a normal bitbake occurs? What can cause the patch failure?

Comment: it's been cloudy today in Gothenburg and my telepathy superpower doesn't work over the sea; how about you show us the recipe?

Comment: I was gonna get angry about the facetious comment, however you made me look at it now. I figured if it worked normally, it should work under devtool...

Comment: The patch that fails is a patch that introduces an entirely new file. Dunno if that's a weird thing to do?

Comment: absolutely not - patches can create files; will u show us your recipe or you want us to keep stressing our telepathy skills out?

Comment: I'll do what I can. But it isn't a recipe really, just a list of additional kernel patches in a bbappend file.

Comment: how did you create the patch? most likely you misunderstand where the source code is patched from and mess up paths to files.

Comment: It's an inherited project, so I don't know how the patch was generated. Where should the patch be generated from, within the kernel tree? And equally pertinently, why does it normally work and only fail under devtool?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Hmm. It seems to be that the patch patches a file that the recipe itself also adds. Is that a valid thing to do (seems a bit nuts to me).

Answer (score 0):

It happened also to me. Also because, in the last years, devtool changes its behavior. Originally, it was automatically git adding all the files to the srctree (also the one generated from a patch). But now, it does not do it anymore.

So, most likely, the patch fails to apply because the file that need to be patched is not inside the git srctree (because it was generated by another patch and no one git added it).

Answer (score 0):

Devtool is applying patches as commits within 'devtool' branch so patch files are required to contain at least "Subject: commit message"  at the beginning of file. Upatched point in history is tagged as 'devtool-base' and version with all patches applied is tagged 'devtool-patched'.

During building of package patches are applied directly to content of directory/repository as unstaged changes meaning no additional requirements.